# ymaps API 3.0 utils

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В 2 версии api карт был метод `ymaps.util.bounds.containsPoint`. Как его использовать в 3 версии api?

Не нашел этот метод в модуле utils, не нашел ничего в документации. Подскажите пожалуйста.

PS Попробывал сделать метод сам:

```js
export function containsPoint(bounds: LngLatBounds, point: LngLat): boolean {
  if (!bounds || !point) {
    return false
  }

  const [southWest, northEast] = bounds
  const [lonSouthWest, latSouthWest] = southWest
  const [lonNorthEast, latNorthEast] = northEast
  const [lon, lat] = point

  return (lon >= lonSouthWest && lon <= lonNorthEast) &&
  (lat >= latSouthWest && lat <= latNorthEast)
}
```

Создаю событие, для получения актуального `bounds` карты:

```js
new ymaps3.YMapListener({
  layerId: 'bounds',
  onUpdate: handleUpdateBounds,
}),
```

Хендлер:

```js
 function  handleUpdateBounds(updateObject: any): void {
        if (updateObject?.type === 'update') {
          console.log(containsPoint(updateObject?.location?.bounds, [33.586404, 45.13348]))
        }
      },
```

В `updateObject?.location?.bound` приходит странные данные, я не могу попасть в условия, когда функция вернет true. Где я ошибку совершаю?

Comment: Вообще Яндекс не обещал равноценной замены. 3.0 даёт трёхмерную новую карту, но он ещё сырой и не оброс всеми возможностями старой версии. Часть фишек наверняка добавят в будущем. Но сейчас даже если что скрытое такого рода и есть, то пользовательское соглашения Яндекса прямо запрещает подобным пользоваться - только документированные публичные методы.

Comment: @YaCor' Я попробывал самостоятельно сделать этот метод.


Получаю актуальный `bounds` из события `onUpdate` карты. Но это не работает, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

В АПИ 3.0 поменялся порядок координат, при получении гранц карты, так что у вас происходит неверное сравнение для широты. Модифицируйте код следующим образом (Переименовал переменные, чтобы было нагляднее):

```js
export function containsPoint(bounds?: LngLatBounds, point?: LngLat): boolean {
  if (!bounds || !point) return false;

  const [[minLng, maxLat], [maxLng, minLat]] = bounds;
  const [pointLng, pointLat] = point

  return (
    pointLng >= minLng
    && pointLng <= maxLng
    && pointLat >= minLat
    && pointLat <= maxLat
  );
};
```