# Использование setBounds в Yandex Map API 3.0

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

У меня есть небольшой js код на версии api 2.1 который отрисовывает объекты на карте, а затем центрирует карту по этим объектам. для центрирования я использую следующий метод

```
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true})
```

как сделать тоже самое в API 3.0?
нашел только вот такой пост [ymaps API 3.0 utils](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485182/ymaps-api-3-0-utils/1489748#1489748), но там немного другая ситуация

Comment: А в чём именно сложность? В получении границ ваших геообъектов или в том, чтобы задать новую границу для карты? Для второй части ответ вроде простой - map.setLocation({bounds:[[37.6,55.7],[37.5, 55.8]});

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) сложность наверное в том, что в документации это нигде не указано. либо я не туда смотрю, а синтаксис от 2.1. отличается довольно сильно. не могли бы вы подсказать как определить границы уже отрисованных геообъектов? или как определить границы YMapFeature

Comment: Про setLocation и в примерах есть, и в доке написано: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/dg/concepts/map.html#map-parms Про определение bounds объектов вот так сразу что-то не вижу, попробую покопать поглубже.

Answer (score 0):

Обратился с эти вопросом в техподдержку Яндекса. Вот, что они мне ответили:

"Задать границы видимости карты с отображением всех объектов, вы можете "пройдясь" по всем точкам: найти минимальную широту и минимальную долготу (это будет первая точка для bounds), и максимальную широту и максимальную долготу (это будет вторая точка для bounds). Для подобных расчетов вы можете использовать готовые либы, например turfjs.org.

Однако с таким упрощенным расчетом могут быть проблемы, если точки с двух сторон от 180 меридиана."

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой, только при клике по кластеру.
Возможно ответ будет в этой статье [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1521744/yandex-map-3-0-zoom-при-клике-на-кластер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1521744/yandex-map-3-0-zoom-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)